# lombok EqualsAndHashCode for List.indexOf()

Tags: java, collections, lombok

I have a class named MyClass that uses lombok annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })`. The property id is of type String. With this I would assume that when I have a collection of these classes i.e. `List<MyClass> classes` and I call the method `.indexOf()` with a string value that is equal to id of one of the objects in the collection I expect it to return the index of that object, but it returns -1. I guess java collections doesn't recognize the lombak annotations? Any idea?

Comment: Does your `equals` method satisfy [all of the properties it's supposed to have](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: You need to call indexOf on an instance of MyClass...

Comment: Your `MyClass` is not going to be equal to a `String`, no matter how you do it.  There isn't going to be a shortcut to avoid the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I could do it by adding a constructor MyClass(String id){ this.id = id; } and then calling classes.indexOf(new MyClass("123")) :). This may not be efficient but works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Louis already wrote, *Your MyClass is not going to be equal to a String, no matter how you do it. There isn't going to be a shortcut to avoid the loop*.

Why? `String` knows nothing about `MyClass`, so it'll never `equals` to it.

A proper equals must be symmetric and Lombok does it job correctly, so `MyClass` will never `equals` to any `String`. You could make your own broken `equals`, but this is an extremely stupid idea.

> I guess java collections doesn't recognize the lombak annotations?

That's not how it works. Lombok modifies the AST as if you wrote a code including the boilerplate. You can even look at it using Delombok. Guava sees only the compile generated code, so there's nothing to recognize.

> I could do it by adding a constructor MyClass(String id){ this.id = id; } and then calling classes.indexOf(new MyClass("123")) :). This may not be efficient but works

Yes, that's the way it goes. You may also write your own loop or use Guava's predicate or some Java 8 feature. But most of the time, your solution is the simplest and best and you'll probably unable to measure any speed difference.